# How do I detect error in shared hosting/live server?

Tags: php

In localhost, we can easily find the errors like missing semicolon in line number xxx, undefined variable in line number xxx,class already declared etc. But, when I upload all my files in shared hosting and try to see results in the web browser, I get to see same error page everytime and it's really really hard to detect what exactly caused the error. The project which i uploaded to the live server was written in laravel. I have tried 'Display errors On' in php.ini, error_reporting(E_ALL). I have even checked the error_log in the root directory but, those logs are usually from few days ago. [error image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42w8N.png)

Any possible solutions ? Or should I switch to server where proc_open is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors
Laravel handles errors and can write them in a log file.
You can customize it if you want, but I don't think it's necessary to do so.

If you dont use any frameworks or ones that don't support such a feature for that matter you could always use the native PHP function `set_error_handler` and catch errors and write them in a log file.

Note: BEWARE of the excessive log file size. If your project has a lot of visitors or has lots of notices and warnings, this log files can get excessively massive, unreadable, and consuming your space. Don't turn it off, it's always good to know where are the errors, but check and debug them often and delete them when not needed.

Comment: Although not in every context, set_error_handler works for most of the context. Any beginner should find it useful for their project.